# code not entering the paint() method and eventually not drawing my game screen

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

basicly im triyng to make a multiplayer snake game for a hobbie project but im just stuck with this white screen (because the graphics don't draw nothing) for like a month. I tried to re organiza the code, using the code without the paint method, just an infinite while and then i just freaked out, any ideas ?Main Client

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

 public class Main {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         JFrame frame = new JFrame();
         Gameplay gameplay = new Gameplay();

         frame.setBounds(10, 10, 905, 700);
         frame.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
         frame.setResizable(false);
         frame.setVisible(true);
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.add(gameplay);
     }
 }
```

Client Gameplay

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Gameplay extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener, Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Socket socket;

    private int[] snakeXLength = new int[750];
    private int[] snakeYLength = new int[750];

    private boolean left = false;
    private boolean right = false;
    private boolean up = false;
    private boolean down = false;
    ArrayList<Boolean> arrows = new ArrayList<Boolean>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        {
            add(left);
            add(right);
            add(up);
            add(down);
        }
    };

    private int snakeLength = 3;
    private boolean dead = false;

    int keyCode;
    private Timer timer;
    private int delay = 100;
    private ImageIcon bodyImage;

    private int[] foodXPosList = {25,50,75,100,125,150,175,200,225,250,275,300,325,
            350,375,400,425,450,475,500,525,550,575,600,625,650,675,700,725,750,
            775,800,825,850};
    private int[] foodYPosList = {75,100,125,150,175,200,225,250,275,300,325,
            350,375,400,425,450,475,500,525,550,575,600,625};
    private ImageIcon foodImage;

    private boolean started = false;

    private int deads = 0;

    private int moves = 0;

    private ImageIcon titleImage;

    private int playersConnected;

    ObjectInputStream receive;
    ObjectOutputStream send;
    Server.ClientVariables server;

    public Gameplay() {
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        timer = new Timer (delay, this);
        timer.start();

        try{

            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 666);

        }catch(UnknownHostException ex1){

            System.out.println("Server unknown");
            System.exit(1);

        }catch(IOException ex2){
            System.out.println("Error starting the server");
            System.exit(1);

        }
    }

    public class ServerVariables {
        boolean dead = false;
        int snakeLength;
        int[] snakeXLength = new int[750];
        int[] snakeYLength = new int[750];
        ArrayList<Boolean> arrows;
    }

    public void sleep(int time) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    ServerVariables serverVariables = new ServerVariables();
    public void paint (Graphics graphics) { 
        try {
            receive = Objects.requireNonNull(new ObjectInputStream(receive));
            server = Objects.requireNonNull((Server.ClientVariables) receive.readObject());
            send = Objects.requireNonNull(new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //image border
            graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            graphics.drawRect(24, 10, 851, 55);

        //title image
            titleImage = new ImageIcon("assets/snaketitle.jpg");
            titleImage.paintIcon(this, graphics, 25, 11);

        //border of gameplay
            graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            graphics.drawRect(24, 74, 851, 577);

        //background
            graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            graphics.fillRect(25, 75, 850, 575);

        //score
            graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            graphics.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.PLAIN, 14));
            graphics.drawString("Score: " + (server.snake[server.id].snakeLength - 2), 780, 30);

        //Length of snake text
            graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            graphics.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.PLAIN, 14));
            graphics.drawString("Length: " + snakeLength, 780, 50);


        //snake
            //array of all mouth image objects
            ImageIcon[] mouth = {
                    new ImageIcon("assets/leftMouth.png"),
                    new ImageIcon("assets/rightMouth.png"),
                    new ImageIcon("assets/upMouth.png"),
                    new ImageIcon("assets/downMouth.png")
            };
            ImageIcon[] enemyMouth = {
                    new ImageIcon("assets/leftMouth_black.png"),
                    new ImageIcon("assets/rightMouth_black.png"),
                    new ImageIcon("assets/upMouth_black.png"),
                    new ImageIcon("assets/downMouth_black.png")
            };

            //the starting snake size

            if (moves == 0) {
                //the starting mouth position
                mouth[1].paintIcon(this, graphics, snakeXLength[0], snakeYLength[0]);   

                //starting position
                snakeXLength [0] = 100;
                snakeXLength [1] = 75;
                snakeXLength [2] = 50;

                switch(server.id) {
                    case 0:
                        snakeYLength [0] = 100;
                        snakeYLength [1] = 100;
                        snakeYLength [2] = 100;
                    case 1:
                        snakeYLength [0] = 200;
                        snakeYLength [1] = 200;
                        snakeYLength [2] = 200;
                    case 2:
                        snakeYLength [0] = 300;
                        snakeYLength [1] = 300;
                        snakeYLength [2] = 300;
                    case 3:
                        snakeYLength [0] = 400;
                        snakeYLength [1] = 400;
                        snakeYLength [2] = 400;
                }

            }
            else {
                snakeXLength = server.snake[server.id].snakeXLength;
                snakeYLength = server.snake[server.id].snakeYLength;
                snakeLength = server.snake[server.id].snakeLength;
            }       

            //changing the mouth according to the pressed key and creating the snake
            for(int i=0; i<snakeLength; i++) {
                if (i==0) {
                    for(int a=0; a<arrows.size(); a++) {
                        if (arrows.get(a)) {
                            mouth[a].paintIcon(this, graphics, snakeXLength[i], snakeYLength[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    bodyImage = new ImageIcon("assets/bodyImage.png");
                    bodyImage.paintIcon(this, graphics, snakeXLength[i], snakeYLength[i]);
                }
            }


        //win
            deads = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<=3; i++) {
                if(i == server.id) {
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    if (server.snake[i].dead) {
                        deads+=1;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (deads == 3) {
                if (!server.snake[server.id].dead) {
                    graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    graphics.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 50));
                    graphics.drawString("VICTORY", 300, 300);
                    graphics.drawString("Your score was " + (server.snake[server.id].snakeLength - 2), 300, 340);

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        serverVariables.dead = true;
                        send.writeObject(serverVariables);
                        send.flush();
                        System.exit(0);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Error closing the server");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }

            }


        //snake collision
            for(int i=1; i<snakeLength; i++) {
                if(snakeXLength[i] == snakeXLength[0] && snakeYLength[i] == snakeYLength[0]) {      
                    for(int a=0; a<arrows.size(); a++) {
                        arrows.set(a, false);
                    }

                    graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    graphics.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 50));
                    graphics.drawString("Game Over", 300, 300);
                    graphics.drawString("Your score was " + (server.snake[server.id].snakeLength - 2), 300, 340);
                    graphics.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
                    graphics.drawString("Space to Exit", 400, 380);
                    dead = true;
                    try {
                        serverVariables.dead = true;
                        for (int a = 0; a<4; a++) {
                            if(serverVariables.arrows.get(i)) {
                                serverVariables.arrows.set(i, false);
                            }
                        }
                        send.writeObject(serverVariables);
                        send.flush();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Error sending snake data to server");
                    }
                }
            }

        //Dead
            if (server.snake[server.id].dead) {
                for(int a=0; a<arrows.size(); a++) {
                    arrows.set(a, false);
                }

                graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                graphics.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 50));
                graphics.drawString("Game Over", 300, 300);

                graphics.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
                graphics.drawString("Score: " + (server.snake[server.id].snakeLength - 2), 350, 340);

                sleep(5);
                System.exit(0);
            }

        //food
                foodImage = new ImageIcon("assets/food.png");
                for (int i = 0;i<server.food.length;i++) {
                    foodImage.paintIcon(this, graphics, foodXPosList[server.food[i].foodXPos], foodYPosList[server.food[i].foodYPos]);
                }
        //waiting room
        if (server.started == false) {
            graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            graphics.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 50));
            playersConnected = 4;
            for (Server.Snake snake : server.snake) {
                if (snake.snakeXLength[0] != 100) {
                    playersConnected-=1;
                }
            }
            graphics.drawString("Waiting for players to connect: " + playersConnected + "/4", 200, 200);        
        }
        else if(!started){
            graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            graphics.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 100));
            graphics.drawString("3", 430, 350); 
            sleep(1000);
            graphics.drawString("2", 430, 350); 
            sleep(1000);
            graphics.drawString("1", 430, 350); 
            sleep(1000);
            graphics.drawString("GO", 420, 350);    
            arrows.set(1, true);
            started = true;
        }
        if(server.started) {
            for (Server.Snake snake : server.snake) {
                if (snake == server.snake[server.id]) {
                    continue;
                }
                else if (snake.dead == false) {
                    if (moves == 0) {
                        //the starting mouth position
                        enemyMouth[1].paintIcon(this, graphics, snake.snakeXLength[0], snake.snakeYLength[0]);  

                        //starting position
                        snake.snakeXLength [0] = 100;
                        snake.snakeXLength [1] = 75;
                        snake.snakeXLength [2] = 50;

                        switch(snake.id) {
                            case 0:
                                snake.snakeYLength [0] = 100;
                                snake.snakeYLength [1] = 100;
                                snake.snakeYLength [2] = 100;
                            case 1:
                                snake.snakeYLength [0] = 200;
                                snake.snakeYLength [1] = 200;
                                snake.snakeYLength [2] = 200;
                            case 2:
                                snake.snakeYLength [0] = 300;
                                snake.snakeYLength [1] = 300;
                                snake.snakeYLength [2] = 300;
                            case 3:
                                snake.snakeYLength [0] = 400;
                                snake.snakeYLength [1] = 400;
                                snake.snakeYLength [2] = 400;
                        }

                    }

                    //changing the mouth according to the pressed key and creating the snake
                    for(int i=0; i<snake.snakeLength; i++) {
                        if (i==0) {
                            for(int a=0; a<snake.arrows.size(); a++) {
                                if (snake.arrows.get(a)) {
                                    enemyMouth[a].paintIcon(this, graphics, snake.snakeXLength[0], snake.snakeYLength[0]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            bodyImage = new ImageIcon("assets/bodyImage_black.png");
                            bodyImage.paintIcon(this, graphics, snake.snakeXLength[i], snake.snakeYLength[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        graphics.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        timer.start();

    if(arrows.get(0)) {
        for(int a=snakeLength-1; a>=0; a--) {
            snakeYLength[a+1] = snakeYLength[a];
        }

        for(int a=snakeLength; a>=0; a--) {
            if (a==0) {
                snakeXLength[a] = snakeXLength[a] - 25;
            }
            else {
                snakeXLength[a] = snakeXLength[a-1];
            }
            if (snakeXLength[a] < 25) {
                snakeXLength[a] = 850;
            }
        }
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream send = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            serverVariables.snakeXLength = snakeXLength;
            serverVariables.snakeYLength = snakeYLength;
            serverVariables.snakeLength = snakeLength;
            serverVariables.arrows = arrows;
            send.writeObject(serverVariables);
            send.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error sending snake data to server");
        }
        //run the paint() method again
        repaint();
    }

    else if(arrows.get(1)) {
        for(int a=snakeLength-1; a>=0; a--) {
            snakeYLength[a+1] = snakeYLength[a];
        }

        for(int a=snakeLength; a>=0; a--) {
            if (a==0) {
                snakeXLength[a] = snakeXLength[a] + 25;
            }
            else {
                snakeXLength[a] = snakeXLength[a-1];
            }
            if (snakeXLength[a] > 850) {
                snakeXLength[a] = 25;
            }
        }
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream send = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            serverVariables.snakeXLength = snakeXLength;
            serverVariables.snakeYLength = snakeYLength;
            serverVariables.snakeLength = snakeLength;
            serverVariables.arrows = arrows;
            send.writeObject(serverVariables);
            send.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error sending snake data to server");
        }
        //run the paint() method again
        repaint();
    }

    else if(arrows.get(2)) {
        for(int a=snakeLength-1; a>=0; a--) {
            snakeXLength[a+1] = snakeXLength[a];
        }

        for(int a=snakeLength; a>=0; a--) {
            if (a==0) {
                snakeYLength[a] = snakeYLength[a] - 25;
            }
            else {
                snakeYLength[a] = snakeYLength[a-1];
            }
            if (snakeYLength[a] < 75) {
                snakeYLength[a] = 625;
            }
        }
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream send = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            serverVariables.snakeXLength = snakeXLength;
            serverVariables.snakeYLength = snakeYLength;
            serverVariables.snakeLength = snakeLength;
            serverVariables.arrows = arrows;
            send.writeObject(serverVariables);
            send.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error sending snake data to server");
        }
        //run the paint() method again
        repaint();
    }

    else if(arrows.get(3)) {
        for(int a=snakeLength-1; a>=0; a--) {
            snakeXLength[a+1] = snakeXLength[a];
        }

        for(int a=snakeLength; a>=0; a--) {
            if (a==0) {
                snakeYLength[a] = snakeYLength[a] + 25;
            }
            else {
                snakeYLength[a] = snakeYLength[a-1];
            }
            if (snakeYLength[a] > 625) {
                snakeYLength[a] = 75;
            }
        }
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream send = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            serverVariables.snakeXLength = snakeXLength;
            serverVariables.snakeYLength = snakeYLength;
            serverVariables.snakeLength = snakeLength;
            serverVariables.arrows = arrows;
            send.writeObject(serverVariables);
            send.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error sending snake data to server");
        }
        //run the paint() method again
        repaint();
    }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

        if (server.started) {
            if (dead) {
                //space
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                    System.exit(1);
            }
            }
            else {
                switch( keyCode ) { 
                //arrows
                    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                        if(!arrows.get(1)) {
                            arrows.set(0, true);
                            arrows.set(3, false);
                            arrows.set(2, false);
                            moves++;
                        }          
                        break;                      
                    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT :
                        if(!arrows.get(0)) {
                            arrows.set(1, true);
                            arrows.set(3, false);
                            arrows.set(2, false);
                            moves++;
                        } 
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                        if(!arrows.get(3)) {
                            arrows.set(2, true);
                            arrows.set(1, false);
                            arrows.set(0, false);
                            moves++;
                        } 
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                        if(!arrows.get(2)) {
                            arrows.set(3, true);
                            arrows.set(1, false);
                            arrows.set(0, false);
                            moves++;
                        } 
                        break;
                //WASD    
                    case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                        if(!arrows.get(1)) {
                            arrows.set(0, true);
                            arrows.set(3, false);
                            arrows.set(2, false);
                            moves++;
                        }          
                        break;                      
                    case KeyEvent.VK_D :
                        if(!arrows.get(0)) {
                            arrows.set(1, true);
                            arrows.set(3, false);
                            arrows.set(2, false);
                            moves++;
                        } 
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                        if(!arrows.get(3)) {
                            arrows.set(2, true);
                            arrows.set(1, false);
                            arrows.set(0, false);
                            moves++;
                        } 
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                        if(!arrows.get(2)) {
                            arrows.set(3, true);
                            arrows.set(1, false);
                            arrows.set(0, false);
                            moves++;
                        } 
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {   
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Server

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Server {
    Random random = new Random();

    Food initialFoods = new Food() {
        {
            foodXPos = random.nextInt(34);
            foodYPos = random.nextInt(23);
        }
    };
    //se só aparecer 1 fruta ou der erro criar mais 1 objeto Food
    Food[] food = {initialFoods, initialFoods};

    Snake[] snake = {};
    ArrayList<Snake> usedSnakes;

    final int port= 666;
    ServerSocket server;

    int id = 0;
    int usersConnected = 0;

    public Server() {
        startServer();
    }

    public class ClientVariables {
        int id;
        Snake[] snake;
        Food[] food;
        boolean started;

    }

    public class Snake {
        int id;
        boolean dead = false;
        int snakeLength;
        int[] snakeXLength = new int[750];
        int[] snakeYLength = new int[750];
        ArrayList<Boolean> arrows = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    }
    public class Food {
        int foodXPos = random.nextInt(34);
        int foodYPos = random.nextInt(23);
    }

    public void transformVariables (Gameplay.ServerVariables in, int id) {
        snake[id].dead = in.dead;
        snake[id].snakeLength = in.snakeLength;
        snake[id].snakeXLength = in.snakeXLength;
        snake[id].snakeYLength = in.snakeYLength;
        snake[id].arrows = in.arrows;   
    }


    private void startServer() {
        try {

            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            while(id<4){
                System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect");
                Socket client = server.accept();
                System.out.println("Client connected ");


                ClientThread clientThread = new ClientThread(client, id);
                clientThread.start();
                id+=1;
                usersConnected+=1;
            }
        }catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println("Error starting the server");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }


    class ClientThread extends Thread{
        ClientVariables clientVariables = new ClientVariables();
        Gameplay.ServerVariables read;
        ObjectOutputStream out;      
        ObjectInputStream in;
        Socket client;
        InputStream inputStream;
        int deads;
        int id;

        public ClientThread(Socket client, int id) {
            this.client = client;
            this.id = id;
            try{
                inputStream = client.getInputStream();
                out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());      
                in = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);   

            }catch(IOException ex){
                System.out.println("Client Disconnected");
            }
        }

        public void run() {
            try {  
                while (true) {
                    read = (Gameplay.ServerVariables) in.readObject();  

                    if (read.dead) {
                        snake[id].dead = true;
                        break;
                    }           
                    transformVariables(read, id);

                    //check for game finished
                    deads = 0;
                    for (Snake snake : snake) {
                        if (snake.dead) {
                            snake.dead = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (deads == 4) {
                        System.out.println("Game finished");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }

                    //check for collisions(food or snakes)
                    usedSnakes = new ArrayList<Snake>();
                    for (Snake firstSnake : snake) {
                        for (Food food : food) {
                            if (firstSnake.snakeXLength[0] == food.foodXPos && firstSnake.snakeYLength[0] == food.foodYPos) {
                                firstSnake.snakeLength+=1;
                                food.foodXPos = random.nextInt(34);
                                food.foodYPos = random.nextInt(23);
                            }
                        }
                        for (Snake otherSnake : snake) {
                            if (firstSnake == otherSnake) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            for (Snake singleSnake : usedSnakes) {
                                if (otherSnake == singleSnake) {
                                    continue;
                                }
                            }
                            for (int bodyPart : otherSnake.snakeXLength) {
                                if (firstSnake.snakeXLength[0] == bodyPart) {
                                    if (bodyPart == otherSnake.snakeXLength[0]) {
                                        snake[firstSnake.id].dead = true;
                                        snake[otherSnake.id].dead = true;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        snake[firstSnake.id].dead = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                        //Sending the data back to the client
                            //server variables
                                clientVariables.id = id;
                                clientVariables.snake = snake;
                                clientVariables.food = food;
                                if (usersConnected == 4) {
                                    clientVariables.started = true;
                                }
                                else {
                                    clientVariables.started = false;
                                }
                                out.writeObject(clientVariables);
                                out.flush();
                }
            }
            catch(SocketException e) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                    in.close();  
                    client.close();
                    System.out.println("Error3");
                    System.out.println("Client disconnected");  
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    System.out.println("Error2");
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }      
            }catch(IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error1");
                System.out.println("Client disconnected");
            }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Error0");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server();

    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the painting for this component be done in paintComponent()?

Comment: For what i saw about the painting method and the paintComponent i realized that doesn't mind wich one i use, its every time white screen whitout anything

Comment: Have you tried paintComponent() without changing paint()?

Comment: Yes i did, i got more inside on the debugging and actually the problem is with the line115 of the gameplay file, for some reason he is sticking there and to close the file i need to get on the task manager (i have "setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);")

Comment: 1) Swing components should be added to then frame BEFORE the frame is made visible 2) Sockets block so they should be executed in a separate Thread to prevent the EDT from blocking 3) the paintComponent() method is the proper place for custom painting 4) A painting method is for painting only. It should NOT have any code related to your socket. If should NOT create Icons. It should NOT change the state of your class.

Comment: Wow, so much things to train, i have 1 question, any good website to find information about that ? I haven't found such a great information just by looking at the documentation!

Comment: Don't put all you game logic into the `paint` method, this is going to make the repaints very slow.  This is what you "main game loop" should be doing.  Also, don't make blocking callings in the paint method, things like `receive.readObject()` are a bad idea here, they should be getting handled by a seperate thread and the synchronised with the game model

Comment: Start with [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).  The point is, paining should run as fast as possible and should only focus on painting the current state of the component. You may also want to look at [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: I'd also look at [All About Sockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html) - but remember, reading/writing to sockets is blocking/slow work - these need to handled by a seperate thread - which is why I'd highlight [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: I'd also avoid using `KeyListener`, it's well known for not working when you expect it to - instead, make use of the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)